# Treeview gem for Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, treeview

Is there a good treeview plugin for Ruby on Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) excellent as i have implemented it successfully on 2 sites, and no problems with it. Checkout [ancestry railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry).

If you are looking at something with a bit more flexibility and power try out jstree [here](http://www.jstree.com/), although the learning curve is quite steep and you will need some background in jquery.

Hope it helps